# mysql 5.7 load_file does not work when running on Debian Stretch

Tags: mysql, insert, debian, blob

I am unable to get load_file to function correctly for a mediumtext column on mysql 5.7.  I created the table with the attach2 column with not null attribute.   An insert command "

```
    insert into attachments (user_id, prop_id, attach2)  values(2, 10,
         LOAD_FILE('/tmp/advantagesSocial.pdf'));"
```

results in "ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'attach2' cannot be null".

When I perform a select statement using load_file: "select load_file(/tmp/advantagesSocial.pdf');" I get the following:

```
        mysql> select load_file('/tmp/advantagesSocial.pdf');
    +-------------------------------------------+
    | load_file('/tmp/advantagesSocial.pdf')    |
    +-------------------------------------------+
    | NULL                                      |
    +-------------------------------------------+
```

I get the same result when attempting to use load_file for a simple text file.

Help!!!  Please!!!

Comment: So what is in that file?

Comment: Check: *"If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns `NULL`."*, see [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the variables "secure_file_priv";
This variable is used to limit the effect of data import and export operations, such as those performed by the LOAD DATA and the LOAD_FILE() function. 
Mysql>  show global variables like '%secure%';

Comment: I am running Debian Stretch (9) and had been running 'mariabdb'.  I researched the problem and had encountered quite a few references to the 'secure_file_priv' variable.  On my mariadb it was not set.  I tried setting it and it still did not work.  I also made sure it was owned by 'mysql' owner and group as well.  Still no go....    I investigated whether mariadb used some other command to load a blob and came up dry, so eventually I decided to uninstall mariadb and drop back to mysql 5.7.

Comment: I forgot to check the 'secure_file_priv' under 5.7.  I just checked it and found it was set to: '/var/lib/mysql-files'.  So I relocated my intended pdf file to that directory, again setting the ownership and group, and voila`, it worked for both the simple select and the desired insert commands.  

Thank you very much,

Arthur Sera